# work of -z in unix

Tags: unix

```
if [ -z "${ABC}" ] 
then
LOGDIR=`${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -cp ${a}/aim.jar my.app.util.GetLogDir "${rsp}"`
```

Can some one help me with this. What this if is exactly doing.
Is it checking if abc exists and the calling GetLogDir's main with some arguments?

Comment: Man test is your friend.

Comment: @wildplasser: Yes, but that's not at all obvious if you don't know that `[` is an alternate name for the `test` command. Actually `man [` should work. And `test` and `[` are likely to be shell built-ins in addition to external commands (they are in bash).

Comment: Thanks Keith...coz of u I learned something today!

Comment: @KeithThompson: I know that and was only pointing the OP into the right direction, instead of copy/pasting entire manpages here. The `[ --> test` thing used to be a secret (I did not even check if a manpage for '[' existed ;-) And, for the syntax/semantics point of view, the built-in property should not make any difference.

Comment: @wildplasser: `/usr/bin/[` and the built-in `[` (and likewise for `test`) should behave the same way *in this case*, but bash's `[` may have additional features that `/usr/bin[` lacks. That's important to  know if you might need to port your script from bash to some other Bourne-derived shell.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I think that -z and -n are pretty common. Relying on bash-extentions is a bad thing, IMO. (I still prefer shebanging with /bin/sh, where possible)

Comment: Would be nice to have this on Unix SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
   -z string
              True if the length of string is zero.
```

To check whether `ABC` is empty. If it is then the command will be executed and result will be in the `LOGDIR`.

Answer (score 3):

From man test:

```
 -z string                   True if  the  length  of  string
                             string is zero.
```